# Does proficiency work on natural armor?

Tags: dnd-5e, armor, proficiency

If I have a PC that has natural armor giving 13+Dex if he wears no armor, will proficiency have any effect on that (or does no proficiency exist for natural armor)?.

Comment: What feature is giving them the natural armour?

Comment: @Someone_Evil  not sure if there is. I found a few lizardmen races but not sure if they are homebrew or not or if there is anything else that gives them natural armor raw wise. but each entry I found was similarily worded) thus ÄI got curious how it all works together

Comment: Ahh Lizardfolk (Volo's) do have a racial trait called Natural Armor which matches your description. Annoying that it has the same name as the monster concept of natural armor, but here we are.

Comment: @Someone_Evil yepp I wasnt even sure if there is a diff. between those two in addition :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Natural armor is not "wearing armor".

The rules for Armor Proficiency state:

> **Armor Proficiency**. Anyone can put on a suit of armor or strap a shield to an arm. Only those proficient in the armor's use know how to wear it effectively, however. Your class gives you proficiency with certain types of armor. *If you wear armor that you lack proficiency with*, you have disadvantage on any ability check, saving throw, or attack roll that involves Strength or Dexterity, and you can't cast spells.
>
> — *Player's Handbook*, p. 144

Since Natural Armor is not "wearing armor", there is no penalty for not having "Natural Armor proficiency", which doesn't even exist.

If Natural Armor counted as "wearing armor", every creature with natural armor would have disadvantage on any ability check, saving throw, or attack roll that involves Strength or Dexterity, and would not be able to cast spells. Ever. Which is obviously not the case.